# Set a band's height dynamically in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I'm doing a project to facilitate the creation of reports with `DynamicJasper` and I got to a part where I have to position an element that is in the `Band PageHeader` manually, set the position X and Y, and this is done after the generation of the report by `DynamicJasper`, the problem is that after I position the element the height of the `Band PageHeader` remains the same even with the element in another position and there is an empty space between the `Band PageHeader` and the other `Bands` below.
So I was wondering if it is possible to set the `height` of the `Band PageHeader` dynamically so that this space is not left empty?

Final code where I build the `DynamicJasper` report and where I want to do this:

```
final DynamicReport dynamicReport = this.fastReportBuilder.build();
dynamicReport.setAllowDetailSplit(true);

final JasperReport jasperReport = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(dynamicReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), null);

((JRDesignBand) jasperReport.getPageHeader()).setHeight(200); // <- Does not work :S

final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados));

this.templateBuilder.setPageObjectsPosition(jasperPrint);
//... more code ...//
```

Edit1: my english is very primitive, sorry for any wrong translation :v